# What functions qualify to be called measures of dispersion by statistician?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

What functions qualify to be called measures of dispersion by statisticians?

Why there are so many of these?

Comment: Notions like dispersion, location, skewness or heavy-tailedness are notoriously imprecise - there are many ways of operationalizing them that emphasize different aspects of distributions differently.

Comment: I fixed the grammar; I also changed "too" to "so", but perhaps you actually meant "too".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a nice explanation in the [link I posted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion#Measures_of_statistical_dispersion) in your previous question:

> A measure of statistical dispersion is a nonnegative real number that is zero if all the data are the same and increases as the data become more diverse.

The reason why there are so many is the same I stated before: different measures provide informations about different features of a distribution. Some of them are based on quantiles, some others are based on moments ...

Answer (score 2):

A more formal framework for discussing measures of dispersion was given in

P.J. Bickel and E.L. Lehmann. 1976. 
Descriptive Statistics for Nonparametric Models. III. Dispersion. 
*Annals of Statistics* 4: 1139-1158.